# constructor does not set member variables, but declares new

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying to build an array with objects based on an external text-file.
However the constructor of the class does not set the member variables of the class.
Instead it declares new variables with the name of the values.

What am I doing wrong?

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => slgDate Object
        (
            [date] => 
            [day] => 
            [info] => 
            [13.01.2020] => 13.01.2020
            [Mon] => Mon
            [] => 
        )

    [1] => slgDate Object
        (
            [date] => 
            [day] => 
            [info] => 
            [10.02.2020] => 10.02.2020
            [Mon] => Mon
            [] => 
        )
//...
)
```

**Code**

```
class slgDate {
    public $date, $day, $info;

    function __construct($date, $day, $info = "Training") {
        $this->$date = $date;
        $this->$day = $day;
        $this->$info = $info;
    }
}

function getDates($f) {

    $file = fopen($f, "r");
    $dates = [];
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $fileGet = trim(fgets($file), "\r\n");
        $expld = explode(';', $fileGet);
        if (($date = strtotime($expld[0])) !== false) {
            $info = $expld[1];
            $strDate = date('d.m.Y', $date);
            $strDay = date('D', $date);
            $newDate = new slgDate($strDate, $strDay, $info);
            array_push($dates, $newDate);
        }
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: Change your property assignments to remove the `$` after the arrow operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access member properties without the leading `$`:

So this means:

```
$this->date
```

instead of

```
$this->$date
```